# How can I keep a metal post from rusting?

Tags: post, rust-proofing

I'm replacing a mailbox post that rusted at the ground level

Comment: This question already has an answer that sounds like a good one, easy DIY   http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4842/how-do-i-rust-proof-a-metal-pole?rq=1

Comment: Agree with the above, but if your root cause is dog urine, then regular rinsing will help with longevity. If you don't have dogs in the area, ignore this advice.

Comment: Zinc Cromate works good on aluminum but I would use cold galvanizeing spray. I use this on my steel boat trailer that is in salt water regularly and if prepared well prior to being sprayed it last years.